# BIDS 2008 with Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, sql-server-2008-r2, azure-pipelines, bids, azure-boards

I just started working for a company that is still using SQL Server 2008 R2.  We have many stored procedures, SSIS packages, and SSRS reports.

Plan to start doing additional .Net development as well. We currently do not have any source control and code is stored in a combination of someones local disk as well as network share.

My manager is open to suggestions and I would like to propose Azure DevOps as I do have experience working with it from other companies. Also our department is expected to grow over the next few years and I think it would be good to use Azure DevOps as a good foundation.

Lastly, I want to suggest to my manager that we use the Azure Scrum board for tracking development and I think that it will be great to "tie" work from the scrum board to ADO releases.

My questions:

1. Will SQL Server / BIDS 2008 (SSIS, SSRS) work with Azure DevOps? I assume so, but I'm not sure if there are any "gotchas" that may prevent it from working correctly.
2. Will SQL Server/BIDS 2008 work with the Azure CI/CD pipeline?

Thanks!

Comment: Just as a note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/user-guide/about-azure-devops-services-tfs?view=azure-devops):

> Azure DevOps Server is the on-premises offering that's built on a SQL
> Server back end. Customers usually choose on-premises when they need
> their data to stay within their network or when they want access to
> SQL Server reporting services that integrate with Azure DevOps data
> and tools.

Since you need to Azure Devops work with Sql Server, you could use the **Azure Devops Server**.

**For example:**[SSRS reports](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/reporting-services-reports?view=azure-devops-2019&viewFallbackFrom=azure-devops) are available from Azure DevOps Server or TFS when configured with SQL Server Analysis Services.

But azure devops server has requirements for the version of sql server.

The Sql server 2008 only supports TFS 2010 and TFS 2012. If you want to use a newer version of Azure Devops server/TFS, you need to upgrade your Sql Server.

Here is the detailed [Sql Server requirements about the Azure Devop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/requirements?view=azure-devops#azure-sql-database-and-sql-server).